# Indication on main question page that the question is answered

Tags: feature-request

On the main question listing page, if there is indication that the question has an "Accepted Solution", it will help the members. If they are searching, they know this question is solved and if they are contributor, they will know that the particular question doesn't have "Acceptable Solution" yet.

This will save time for both inquirer and contributor.

I understood from answers below that the "Number of Answers" will turn "Yellow" if the question has "Accepted Solution". However, the difference between normal white and yellow is too subtle to miss. In fact, I did not notice until it was pointed out in the answers below. So naturally a casual searcher coming from search engine may miss it too.

Answer (score 2):

With the green tick, the question asker can select answer that best is suited.

On the front page a question with an accepted answer has the number of answers in yellow.

FAQ on accepting: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, you mean if the question has accepted answer the "number of answer" will turn Yellow ?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the answer by Bhuvan Rikka. The green box with yellow 7 answers has an accepted answer and the green box with white 1 answer has none (yet).

Comment: Got it. But it is not very well documented for me to understand. It should probably can have note at the top.

Comment: Added a link to the relevant FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for link, I have one more point, "There should be some indication on the questions page at top" so people know that. For me the difference between white and yellow was subtle that I did not notice until you and Bhuvan pointed out. If this looks correct, Shall I update the main question with this point ?

Comment: @Milind: hover over the number. The tooltip will say, "one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer". In general, when in doubt, hover over stuff. The site is chock-full of useful tooltips.

Comment: @ЯegDwight: Yes, that may sound right to person acquainted with the site. But from user-friendly point of view, it may not be that simple.

Answer (score 2):

We have it already. The yellow coloured number says that the question is answered! (7 in this case)

[image: pic]

Comment: Sorry, But I am not talking about Answer, I am talking about if the question has "Accepted Answer"

Comment: @MilindThakkar That's what i'm saying,the yellow coloured number(7) says that the question has an accepted answer

Comment: Got it. But it is not very well documented for me to understand.

Comment: @MilindThakkar Every SE related site has this feature. The color may be different though.